# How To add another root variable in the response json using CRNK IO

Tags: crnk

I am getting the Current Response below for CRNK IO , But i wanted the JSON Structure to appear Like the Required Response . So things need to be done so that i can get the Final Response JSON Structure as per the Required Response below.

**Current Response**

```
{
 "data" : [
   "countries":[] 
]
}

**Required Response**
{
  "data":[]
  "countries" : []
}
```

Comment: How this question related to groovy?

Comment: i have been coding this over groovy , so i have added groovy

Comment: there is no groovy code in your question - better to remove this tag or add a groovy code.